# Tournament vs gambling

Tags: gambling

In law, would this be considered as gambling - an investment tournament where people pay an entree fee and then pick a portfolio of 3 stocks. After some period the top 3 portfolios share the pot of entry fees.

Comment: Interesting question. I guess it would matter if stock picking was considered a game of luck or a game of skill...are entrants making their own portfolio of 3 stocks, or are they selecting a premade one?

Comment: I presume that is an entry fee and not somehow linked to one's choice of dinner.

Answer (score 1):

In most jurisdictions if it was called an *investment* there would be strict regulation. As a game, it could be said to be skill-based although you don't say what the winning criteria are to be (if the top portfolio is picked at random, you're gambling).